# How to paste table-valued results together in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Imagine that I have a table named TEST with two columns named ID and CONTENT, and that the table has two rows, with the ID values 1 and 2, and the CONTENT values "abc,def,ghi" and "jkl,mno,pqr", that is, the table looks like this:

```
ID | CONTENT
1  | "abc,def,ghi"
2  | "jkl,mno,pqr"
```

Further imagine that I have a table-valued function SPLIT which splits each string into a table of its comma-separated components, i.e. SPLIT("abc,def,ghi") would return a table with one column and three rows containing the values "abc", "def" and "ghi", so that for example SELECT * FROM SPLIT("abc,def,ghi") would return the table:

```
COMPONENT
"abc"
"def"
"ghi"
```

How do I write an SQL query which returns the split strings of the CONTENT column adjoined to their corresponding ID values? That is, I would hope for the result to be:

```
ID | COMPONENT
1  | "abc"
1  | "def"
1  | "ghi"
2  | "jkl"
2  | "mno"
2  | "pqr"
```

I attempted to create an SQL fiddle as an example, but I'm not really much of an SQL professional and couldn't get it to work, so I hope that the above makes sense.

Comment: This is considered a **broken** schema. I know you might not have any control over that, but if you do, push to _change the table design_ so the result of this question is how the data is stored in the first place.

Comment: True, I unfortunately don't have any such control. For context, the design is related to having a hierarchy of collection data stored in the database, so that the actual table that I'm looking it contains rows of "parent hash value" and "collection of element hash values", where the latter is stored as a comma-separated string, and I need to collect all the element hash values across parent hash values.

Comment: @AlexanderSokol what database is this ? MysQL, SQL server, Oracle, postgres?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name like this? I added a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a table valued function SPLIT() then you can write a query like below in MS SQL Server

```
select id,component from test t outer apply SPLIT(t.content)
```